# Decrypt remote file securely with local private key

Tags: linux, ssh-tunnel, encryption, private-key, gnupg

I've created a `alldots.tar` file mainly with dot config files from my local server. I then transferred it to my other (remote) server and there it is, cryptographed.

It didn't occur at the time of creating that I would need the private key there as well, when I tested all locally.

Now I have a big dilemma, because I don't want to send my private key over the web; and the other solution is to wait for the holidays to end so I can physically use the private key usb-stick there.

```
gpgtar --decrypt --gpg-args --homedir=/media/usbstick/.gnupg alldots.tar
```

Maybe there is a solution using ssh tunnels to chage the gpg `--homedir` to grab the private key here at `local` server?

Or any other secure suggestions would be good.

I could create a temporary private key just for that, but that would render the idea in the long run useless, so I would like to use my main private/public key, if possible. Thanks.

Comment: I've solved by a different approach, using password instead of pubkey. But maybe this question should remain, depending if answers given here would help in the future.

Comment: You could copy the remote encrypted file to your local machine (using `scp`), then decrypt it here while piping the output back to the remote server over ssh. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1037636/657482) for examples how to achieve that.